# Unable to receive mail from outside on ubuntu webmin postfix mail server

Tags: 14.04, server, postfix, mail-server, webmin

I have an ubuntu server which is on virtual machine running on windows server. 
I have installed webmin on my ubuntu server to be able to configure mail settings and mail servers.

I've set my adsl 2+ modem+router which it has static ip address to DMZ on virtual circuit setting.

And in ubuntu network interfaces I have set this settings to be able to see the ubuntu server from internet :

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.107
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 4.2.2.4
```

And in Webmin I have set this records which make mail server visible from internet (outside)

[virtual server records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZaHn.png)

but I'm confused why I can not receive mail from internet or outside of my server ?

if you check my domain in http://www.intodns.com it says mx record is missing, but I have set mx record on my server ! 
please help me I'm stuck

Comment: does your ISP allow inbound traffic on port 25?

Answer (score 0):

First problem, I guess, is that name servers for your domain are:

darya1.irandns.com.   ['31.25.89.27']
darya2.irandns.com.   ['31.25.89.27']

as far as I see from DNS. And I guess that's not your system?

So, if you want to configure your domain on your system (with your webmin) you have to delegate domain properly to your system - so DNS knows where to look for your domain's configuration. Now apparently it doesn't - hence it doesn't see your MX server.

Then, if I didn't miss something looking briefly - you define your MX as mail.karshenasan-nezam.com, but you don't have type A record for mail.karshenasan-nezam.com.

And also - if you're trying to run the mail server on your home broadband, even more - as virtual guest, you'll have to make sure that port 25 is properly forwarded from your public IP to your internal private IP (192.168.something.something) - (adsl and/or virtual switch of your hypervisor)

I think that would be anyway a good start for you with investigating the issue.

Comment: thanks for the answer i've changed the records as you said! i'm waiting to see it'll work and i'll let you know